# php echo only in a specific order

Tags: php, html, sql

i have a problem:

```
if(isset($_POST['send'])){  
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id']);
$query = mysql_query("select * from somewhere where id='$id'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array( $query );
  if(!mysql_num_rows($query)==1){
  echo('error');
      }

    }
```

After this i have this echo from db:

```
<input type="text" name="up_name" value="<?php echo $row['name'];?>" id="up_name"/>
```

and this echo:

```
<select>
<?php
$up_id=$_POST['up_id'];
$sqlDateUser=mysql_query("SELECT `something` from `somewhere` where id='".$id."'"); 
$res=mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlDateUser);
$somethig_selected=$res['something'];
$something=mysql_query("SELECT `den` FROM `jud`");
while($row = mysql_fetch_row( $something)){
    $selected=($row[0]==$somethig_selected)?'selected':'';
    echo "<option value='".$row[0]."' ".$selected.">".$row[0]."</option>";
}
?>
</select>
```

In this order all it is ok but if i change it, first echo doesn't work. I need to display and others rows after these and i don't know what is the problem with the second echo. Can someone tell me what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be a naming issue.  For example, you have your second query assigning your values for `mysql_fetch_row` into a variable named `$row`.

That also is the same name you've given your first query, where you are assigning your `mysql_fetch_array`.

I would probably try naming them something different like `$row_get_user_info` and `$row_get_den` to differentiate them.  Also it would make it easier if, when you moved your first `echo` line, that you also move the query that goes along with it.  (Keep them together.)

Comment: Just a mention, you should really start using MySQLi. As of  PHP 5.5.0 the MySQL API is depreciated ;)